# Not able to calculate to what range current date belongs in django?

Tags: django

I have period model and this model has a current property that should calculate what period is current.

```
@with_author
    class Period(CommonInfo):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        order_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        start_date = models.DateField()
        end_date = models.DateField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        is_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        _is_current = models.NullBooleanField( blank=True, null=True, default=None)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s %i %s ' % ("#", self.order_value, self.name)

        def _is_current(self):
            if self.start_date <= datetime.datetime.now().date() <= self.end_date:        
                self._is_current = True
            else:
                self._is_current = False

        @property
        def is_current(self):
            if self._is_current is None:
                self._is_current()
            return self._is_current
```

However it is not calculated and I am not getting any error. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting and where in your code is it being triggered?

Comment: it is triggered . not getting any error just my the flag is not becoming true when it should be.

Comment: After setting `self._is_current` to `True` or `False`, you need to call `self.save()`

Comment: this logic is used  without save and it always works .I use same logic  in  lot of situations. I suspect something is wrong with my condition

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the name of your method, because it is the same as one of your database fields (i.e., `self._is_current` refers to refers to your `NullBooleanField` and to your method for checking if the period is current. Also, you need to call`save()` after updating a field. Try updating (and renaming) your `_is_current()` method as follows:

```
    def period_is_current(self):
        if self.start_date <= datetime.datetime.now().date() <= self.end_date:
            self._is_current = True
        else:
            self._is_current = False
        self.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing. I would just use the property:

```
@property
def is_current(self):
    if not self._is_current:
        self._is_current = (self.start_date <= datetime.datetime.now().date() <= self.end_date)
        self.save()
    return self._is_current
```

Comment: Now I get error no such column: lease_period._is_current

Comment: Did you delete the `_is_current` field? You need to keep that. I meant just remove the secondary `def _is_current()`